# Simple Jquery event

Tags: jquery

Ok here's my code, it works but only 1 cycle through. what am I missing for the event to cycle over and over

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").hide();

            $("button").click(function(){
                $("p").show();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
    <button> click </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/eDpMJ/

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

`toggle()` display or hide the matched elements. So, if it shown initially then it will be hidden on next `button` click and next time it will be shown again. And this cycle will keep on going.

Comment: +1, it seems like the OP needs explanations what he did wrong.

Comment: @Palash FYI: The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9.  Here he is using 1.9.1.

Comment: @user1671639 - not the same toggle()

Comment: @user1671639: Its the jQuery's [Toggle Event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function that has [been removed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfntogglehandler-handler-is-deprecated) as part of version 1.9.

Comment: @adeneo Is there any 2 different toggle() methods?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @user1671639, `toggle` is still active, It even had an update in version 1.8 : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks Palash they did work, but let's pretend toggle doesn't exist. 
How would I code it so I it "loops" through the events.

Comment: @user2440594 - like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVJVL/)! But why would you ?

Comment: @Palash, adeneo, Karl Thanks for correcting me.  I got confused between method and event. My vote for taking time to explain.

Comment: @user1671639: That's why it's removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential for modularity in the library :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the comments is for a smarter way.

To learn how you can loop forever, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7K5eS/

Where I used this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $onScreen = 1;

        $("button").click(function(){
           if ($onScreen == 1)
           {
               $("p").hide();
                $onScreen = 0;
           } else
           {
               $("p").show();
                $onScreen = 1;
           }
        });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Palash: Cool! Didn't know you can do that as well.